# Python: PyQt4 QtGui ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtgui

I have been trying to use PyQt4, but I can never use QtGui. I recieve the following error...

```
    from PyQt4 import QtGui
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

from the following code...

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)  #define the app
win = QtGui.Qwidget()               #define the window
win.show()                          #show the window
```

I think it might be a problem with the installation - I've tried using both the exe installer as well as manually putting the download in the appropriate area. I have also made sure the path variable is correct.

I've also installed Python (Python35) and uninstalled it a number of times - one possible issue is that my python installation always ends up in *C:\Users\Frank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35*

Whenever I install PyQt, I make sure all the appropriate files are put in this directory but still - no luck! I'm out of ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try to use installation packages which include both Python and PyQt4. e.g. http://winpython.github.io